# Insert into TABLE2 has count(CLASS) = 1

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables(TABLE1 and TABLE2)

We fetch the data from TABLE1 and insert into TABLE2 having specific column count = 1

TABLE1 and TABLE2 has same columns (ROLLNO, NAME, CLASS)

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1(ROLLNO NUMBER(3), NAME VARCHAR2(4), CLASS VARCHAR2(2));
CREATE INDEX IDX1 ON TABLE1(CLASS);

CREATE TABLE TABLE2(ROLLNO NUMBER(3), NAME VARCHAR2(4), CLASS VARCHAR2(2));
CREATE INDEX IDX2 ON TABLE2(CLASS);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(100, 'JOHN', '01');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(101, 'ROHN', '01');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(102, 'MAYA', '02');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(103, 'NAYA', '03');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(104, 'SANA', '04');
```

We need to insert the records into TABLE2 from TABLE1 having records based on count of CLASS column value = 1 only.

TABLE2 has following data after fetching data from TABLE1 based on above condition

```
ROLLNO    NAME     CLASS
-------------------------
  102     MAYA       02
  103     NAYA       03
  104     SANA       04
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT CLASS FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY CLASS HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

in the `INSERT` statement to get only the `CLASS`es which occur only once in `TABLE1`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2
WITH cte AS (SELECT CLASS FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY CLASS HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CLASS IN (SELECT CLASS FROM cte);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=26920aa3edbb380a1bc620fe1ee3b00a).

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate `table1` by `class`; since you only need to insert for groups with a row count of 1, you can select `max(rollno)` and `max(name)` (or `min`, it doesn't matter) for each group and use that for insertion. In those cases (when the row count is 1), the `max` or `min` is the same as the one value (in the one row) in the group.

This way you only need to scan `table1` once, rather than twice.

```
insert into table2 (rollno, name, class)
    select max(rollno), max(name), class
    from   table1
    group  by class
    having count(*) = 1
;
```